# extract the user context of the java vm

Tags: java, security

The jvm is running with a security context of some user.

On windows and sometimes on linux, the user will have a kerberos tgt. Is it possible to extract the security context and the kerberos tgt of the user, whose priviliges the jvm is running with.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. The Kerberos credentials are, depending on your exact setup, generally stored in a "keytab" file. This keytab is readable by the user (obviously) and, thus, by Java.

So, *even in the absence of the Java Kerberos-specific functionality* (which does, by the way, exist), it would still be possible to get the user's credentials.